# R Shiny SQLite App: Data retrieving problem

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to retrieve a data from my database which is selected by user. The error I am getting every time is:

**near "carbamazepine": syntax error**

ps: carbamazepine is an element that user has selected.

my sqlite database is as follow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16aGV.png)

i am very new to programming. can anyone help? i have read in internet, the problem might be happening due to wrong data type in sqlite database. can anyone suggest anything? my code is as follow:

global.r

```
# Libraries

library("shiny")
library("RSQLite")
library("dtplyr")
library("dplyr")

# Globar Variables 

db <- dbConnect (SQLite(),
                  "/Users/sudiptobosu/200922/20200714PPCP.sqlite")
# Global Function





names_ppcp = dbGetQuery(db, "Select PPCP FROM mydata")
```

server.r

```
shinyServer(function (input, output, session) {

output$ppcpOut <- reactive({
  input$user1
})  


output$propertyOut <- reactive({
  input$user2
})
  

ppcpquery <- reactive({
  input$user1
})  

query <- reactive({
  paste('SELECT solubility FROM mytable WHERE PPCP = "%s"', ppcpquery())
})


output$valueout <- reactive({
  
  dbGetQuery(db,paste(query()))
  
})

#propertyquery <- eventReactive ({input$user2})  

session$onSessionEnded (function()
  {
  dbDisconnect(db)
})

})
```

ui.r

```
ui <- fluidPage ( 
  titlePanel("bo-DEREC CE"),
  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("user1","Select the PPCP",choices = names_ppcp),
      selectInput("user2","Select the property",choices = c("Solubility","Volatility","Adsorbability","Degradability"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("ppcpOut"),
      textOutput("propertyOut"),
      textOutput("valueout")
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In general it would be easier to figure out what is going wrong here if you provided an example that can run - but looking through your code, where you have this line:
`paste('SELECT solubility FROM mytable WHERE PPCP = "%s"', ppcpquery())`, you probably want this: `sprintf('SELECT solubility FROM mytable WHERE PPCP = "%s"', ppcpquery())`.

`paste` doesn't support using variables like `%s`, you need to use `sprintf` to construct strings in this way.